# Check if the background image is working in Cypress

Tags: cypress

How can I test in Cypress that the background image I get is working and the image is loaded properly in the preview?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I can think of is to test the URL of the background image with a `cy.request()`.

It's a bit involved, but I can't see anything on the page that indicates a failed load for the image.

For example, this simple page:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/paper.gif");
      background-color: #cccccc;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>The background-image Property</h1>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Tests like this,

```js
cy.get('body')
  .should('be.visible')
  .and('have.css', 'background-image', 'url("https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/paper.gif")')
  .then($el => {
    const url = $el.css('background-image').match(/url\("(.*)"\)/)[1]
    cy.request({url, failOnStatusCode: false})
      .its('status')
      .should('eq', 200)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cy.get('yourSelector').should('have.attr', 'height', 'yourHeight');
```

or

```
cy.get('yourSelector').should('have.css', 'background-image');
```

Comment: the first test would be if you want to test stuff like width and height if needed

Comment: Thanks but how would I know that the background image I get is broken or working as expected?

Comment: @Smh sorry for the late reply, simply through cypress showing an error/pass when you run the code, i would suggest just using the test und changing the background image so it is broken. if the test fails, it works